# Convert the categorical integer list iris.target into three binary attribute representation and store the result in variable iris_target_onehot,

Tags: attributeerror

Convert the categorical integer list `iris.target` into three binary attribute representation and store the result in variable `iris_target_onehot`.

I am getting attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'toarray'

```
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
iris_target_onehot = enc.fit(iris.target.reshape(-1, 1))
print(iris_target_onehot.toarray()[[0,50,100]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fit_transform. The code should be

```
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
iris_target_onehot = enc.fit_transform(iris.target.reshape(-1, 1))
print(iris_target_onehot.toarray()[[0,50,100]])
```